# Was ist das Gegenteil von "hervorheben"?

Tags: single-word-request, expression, negation

Beim Schreiben meiner Arbeit bin ich auf folgendes Problem gestoßen: Wie drücke ich (als Verb/Adjektiv) aus, dass etwas *nicht mehr hervorgehoben* ist oder wird?

Es geht dabei z. B. um das Hervorheben von Wörtern in Texten.

> Beim Klick auf "Finden" werden alle Stellen, die den Suchbegriff enthalten, hervorgehoben.
>
> Durch einen Klick auf "Zurück" werden diese Stellen wieder **???**

Die Hervorhebung wird rückgängig gemacht / Zurücksetzen der Hervorhebung / oder Ähnliches klingt sehr steif und unnatürlich.

Wie kann man diese Aktion des *Zurücksetzens der Hervorhebung* möglichst treffend und vor allem kurz bezeichnen!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es kommt auf den Kontext an. In deinem Beispiel suchst du ja nicht nach einem *Gegenteil*, sondern bloß nach dem *Aufheben* der Eigenschaft »hervorgehoben sein«.

Gegenteil, Antonym:

- unterdrücken
- verstecken
- verbergen

Aufhebung:

- gleichstellen oder egalisieren
- anpassen
- angleichen oder ausgleichen

Vorschlag:

> Durch einen Klick auf »Zurück« werden diese Stellen wieder ausgeglichen.

Das klingt zwar ganz leicht ungewöhnlich, um so besser kann man es sich aber merken.

Answer (score 17):

Ich weiß nicht, ob es ein geläufiges Gegenwort gibt; ich würde umformulieren:

> - Durch einen Klick auf „Zurück“ wird die Markierung/Auswahl aufgehoben.
> - Durch einen Klick auf „Zurück“ wird die Hervorhebung rückgängig gemacht.

Comment: +1 for the first, the second sux

Comment: @Sean: well, "Hervorhebung aufgehoben" didn't sound right, so I had to come up with a different verb.

Comment: *Beide* gehen für mich in Ordnung.

Comment: @splattne: "gehen _für_ mich in Ordnung". Sonst wird wieder gefragt, warum man das so sagen kann. ;)

Comment: @trema natürlich, danke für die Korrektur. Vermute, ich hatte eine kurze Störung im Sprachzentrum meines Gehirns. :)

Comment: @splattne: I took the liberty of fixing your comment.